# when posting to facebook from api not visible on friends wall - startpage?

Tags: facebook

Im posting to my wall with the below code, and it is visible on my wall with text and thumbnail image, but why isnt it visible on my friends startpage?

If I post from within facebook then it is visible on my friends walls-startpage aswell as mine, but not if I post with the api?

What can I do to post to my wall and that is posted on all my friends walls aswell?

Im posting with the below.

```
FB.api('myfacebookid/feed/, '{.....
```

I know there is FB.api('FRIENDS_ID/feed/... aswell, but that only post on one of my friends, doesnt it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many things that can affect how things will show up on a friends feed.

- Personal settings of the friend
- How your user is setup to post with the app
- Facebook algorithms (we have no control)

Check in the `stream` table (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream/) to see if the posting exists/is viewable for that user.

Comment: I just created a testuser on facebook, just to see how it looks on his wall when I post to my wall. And for the testuser I didnt do any specific settings.
But when I post it from the api it is not visible on his wall, but if I post from within facebook, it is visible on his wall?

How are people suppose to create something with the api when a basic thing like this is so hard to fix!

Comment: Check in the stream table please.  See if the item exists as viewable for the user as well as viewable for the friend.

Comment: DMCS, thanks.
Im using .api and have added all the permissions that I need, I will have to use facetime with a friend to see what he sees when I upload to my wall.
And take it from there, thanks again!

Comment: Were you able to track it down in the FQL stream table?

Comment: No, Im not using the FQL, I already had all the permissions that I needed, I just have to test with somebody to see for myself how my friends sees it. Thanks :-)

Comment: It is a valid troubleshooting step to see if you can grab it out of the stream table. I've asked you multiple times, why are you refusing to troubleshoot?

Comment: Sorry mom ;-) I will test the FQL.Thanks a lot!